# Geo Proximity Search

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

There is requirement in application which states that find out all the objects that are bounded to specific country and/or city into the google map.

We have objects with respective latitude and longitude precalucated using google map api and stored in database. Some times these objects are provides service withing certain service range/radius within which they can provide their services.

For e.g. now the situation is like i wanna to find out all the objects
which resides in Amsterdam for instance.

The application should find out all the objects that are located in
Amsterdam, also the objects which are not exactly located in Amsterdam
but nearby, having service range up to Amsterdam.

So i have known latitude, longitude values for Amsterdam returned by
google map, also the objects having respective lat,lng value and
service range/radius stored in database. How can i make it possible?

Comment: Shouldn't Amsterdam (or any other location) be represented by an irregular polygon representing the city boundaries?

Comment: God this reminds me of my physics days: assume amsterdam is a sphere...

Comment: Isn't that duplicate of your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610496?

Comment: Yah Vertec, it is little bit simillar. in that situation we have range/radius from both side. But now in this case we have just one.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably represent countries/cities as polygons in the DB, and then use OpenGIS-style polygon intersection functions to intersect.

**But**, MySQL does **not** implement polygon intersection properly (only MBR - Minimum Bounding Rectangle). So this approach, while correct in theory, will simply not work for you with MySQL. You might want to consider moving to Postgres.

What you can do is use your DB's MBR intersection capabilities and supplement them with your own code that does polygon/point intersection (you can find libraries that do this).

Comment: This solution may not work since either i have to change database schema or entire database. Is there another way, for e.g. i can get bounding box in which Amsterdam resides and the object's bounding box whose service range overlaps Amstedam's bounding box

Comment: I don't see how it could work if you don't have the polygon for Amsterdam.

Comment: I'm not sure you can, you'll have to check the documentation. But I'm pretty sure that if you're talking about countries/major cities you can find this information in the web somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at MySQL's [spatial extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/spatial-extensions.html).

You'll need to use the [Contains](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/functions-that-test-spatial-relationships-between-geometries.html#function_contains) function. However, as Paul stated in his comment, regions should be represented as polygons. If they are not, then I believe your best bet is to create a polygon centered on the point you already have.

Comment: How i can compute polygon data based on point which i have? also to use MySQL spatial extension, is there any need to change database structure?

Comment: You use the Polygon functions, or if it's a circle, you can simply use Distance. Yes, you need to use spatial fields and indexes.

Comment: Yes i have to use polygon function, But for polygon function to be used i need set of coordinates that defines my country or city are. Form where we can get that?

Comment: Google Maps, maybe? This is what Paul Tomblin meant in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

OK from What I understand you are basically trying to calculate the distance between 2 lat/long points. I would start by discounting the ones that where outside you sphere of (lets say) 10 miles. So from your central point you will want to get the the coordinates 10 miles, East, West, South and North. To do this you need to use the [Great-circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) formula.

From that point you have you Data if you wish to break this data up further then you need to order the points by distance from the central point. To do this you need to use the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

I can see that you have a PHP tag but I have included some formulas and examples in both SQL(mainly) and C#.

[Haversine Formula in C# and in SQL](http://megocode3.wordpress.com/2008/02/05/haversine-formula-in-c/)

[Determine the distance between ZIP codes using C#](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/programming-and-development/?p=634)

[Great Circle SQL](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=81360)

[Great Circle 2](http://www.bigresource.com/MS_SQL-Great-Circle-distance-calculation-AAuK69yL.html#ZWR4HbHJ)

Comment: Thanx for help. But this only will give you distance between two points.
Also you are assuming that you are going to find  out the points which are in 10 miles range.

Comment: In my case i want to find out points which are in specific country/city (irrespective of range or radius) also the points which are not in this country or city but in nearby region having service that might overlap the country/city boundry

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at something like [LocalSolr](http://www.gissearch.com/localsolr)/[LocalLucene](http://www.gissearch.com/locallucene) if you wanted to leave the mechanics of proximity to an external service.